# Ubuntu 18.04: Workspaces to Dock extension ERROR

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension, extension

Anyone else has problems with the '*Workspaces to Dock*' extension in Ubuntu 18.04?
I can install it with no problem from:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/427/workspaces-to-dock/

But every time I reboot, it does not load, and I see a warning sign in the GNOME Tweaks with the following message:

> Error loading extension

Any clue?

EDIT:

Running the following command, as suggested in the comments, I spotted the following lines, which might be relevant.

`sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell | grep workspaces`

```
Dec 24 13:41:35 dcarbajo-SLIMBOOK gnome-shell[2246]: Extension "workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com" had error: TypeError: Me is null
Dec 24 13:41:35 dcarbajo-SLIMBOOK gnome-shell[2246]: Extension workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com already installed in /home/dcarbajo/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com will not be loaded
```

Comment: the output of the command is over 10K lines, what am I supposed to look for in there? I saw something that might give a clue, see my edit

Comment: You can try installing an older version of the extension manually. Also consider reporting the issue to the developer at GitHub.